# Jest FireEvent returning True with disabled button

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm creating a simple test, where when I have a disabled button, the onClick button should be false, but it's returning true.

**COMPONENT**

```
function AbstainVoteButton({ onAbstainVote, isDisabled }: IProps) {
    return (
        <Button onClick={onAbstainVote} variant='light' disabled={isDisabled}>
            Abstain from Voting
        </Button>
    );
}
```

**TEST**

```
describe('[ABSTAIN VOTE BUTTON] Testing OnClick...', () => {
    test('Should be able to click with disabled button!', async () => {
        const handleClick = jest.fn();
        render(<AbstainVoteButton onAbstainVote={handleClick} isDisabled={true} />);
        const BUTTON = screen.getByText(/Abstain from Voting/i);

        console.log(fireEvent.click(BUTTON));

        expect(BUTTON).toBeEnabled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit confusing, I'm not sure what you mean by "testing that the button is `false`", also your test description suggests your button is supposed to still work even though it's disabled?

In any case, normally what you would test about disabled buttons, is that they do **not** trigger the `onClick` function passed to them:

```
it('does not call handleClick when the button is disabled', async () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();
    render(<AbstainVoteButton onAbstainVote={handleClick} isDisabled />);
    const button = screen.getByText(/Abstain from Voting/i);

    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(handleClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```